# Node: required module not in scope of function inside module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope, eval

I'm having a scoping issue that I seem to unable to elegantly solve.

**Scenario**

The top of my file has a module required in the following way

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

What I am attempting to do, is take a function saved a JSON string and convert it back to a function (using [JSON-fn](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/jsonfn)). Below the require I have something like:

```
module.exports = function() {
  //job[1] is a JSON hash holding the function. More on that in the below text.
  var func = JSONfn.parse(job[1])
  func()
};
```

In the case of a function that has no need of the file's modules, I can invoke the function and it works perfectly.  However, when I try to invoke a function using the moment module, I get the below error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: moment is not defined at eval
```

Despite my best efforts, I cannot seem to get the 'moment' variable into the function's scope. It works if I change my module's require statement to:

```
global.moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

I have tried with multiple different modules, just to confirm it wasn't something specific to moment, and no module I have tested has worked.

**Question**

Is scoping the module to the global object an appropriate way to fix my problem? Or is there some other method of attaching the function to the correct scope?

Thanks in advance for the help and looking forward to reading your suggestions!

Comment: No, `JSON-fn` is coded quite naively and does not support that. But anyhow, *why* do you want to stringify and parse functions???

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the response! I am attempting to hold functions scheduled for Cron in Redis, thus giving me the ability to restart them on server restarts.

Comment: Is it possible for you to do the 'require' inside the function you want to execute?